# Scraping a website built with angular2+ - can't fire a click

Tags: c#, angular, winforms, web-scraping

I want to scrape a website using `c#`, the website is built with `angular2+`.
I have got some amount of success in firing click of button, links, etc.
I am doing thin in winform application and using `browserObject`.

my problem is that:

at one place i have to select a option from dropdown & fire click event.
i have succeed in setting the value in dropdown menu but i can't fire a click

i am using the following code:

```
   var select = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");

   var foundGIAXXXN = false;
   foreach (HtmlElement s in select)
   {
       if (s.GetAttribute("ng-model") == "savedSearchModel")
       {
           var options = s.Children;
           int optionIndex = -1;
           foreach (HtmlElement o in s.Children)
           {
               optionIndex++;
               if (o.InnerText == "GIAGGGVST")
               {
                   s.Children[optionIndex].SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
                   //o.SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
                   s.SetAttribute("class", "ng-valid ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse");
                   foundGIAXXXN = true;
                   break;
               }
           }
       }

       if (foundGIAXXXN)
           break;
   }

   await Sleep(2);


   foreach (HtmlElement b in browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
   {
       if (b.GetAttribute("ng-click") == "vm.getSavedFilterBySaveID(savedSearchModel); isLoadSavedOpen = false;")
       {
           b.InvokeMember("click");
       }
   }
```

Comment: You should try Selenium C#

Comment: Thanks @MataPrasadChauhan , I just asked my friend & the website a want to scrap has an API i can use that to get the data, I am new to working with API so i don't know about this. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that we can not use `C# WebBrowser` class to scrap a web site that is built with `angular2+` or say rather it is very difficult to do so, because `angular` adds many classes in between user interactions that we can not do within `C#`.

Now, i am using an API provided by the site and it is the best way to get data from the website.

**Note:** Do not try to scrap website built with `angular` using `C# WebBrowser` class